# Fix illegal string offset PHP

Tags: php

***CODE***

`Foreach Loop`

```
foreach ($LS::getBase() as $base) {
            $fromDatabaseThumb = $base['base-thumbnail'];
            $fromDatabaseDescription = $base['base-description'];
            $fromDatabaseTitle = $base['base-title'];
        echo " 
        <div style='background-color: #ffffff; width: 725px; height: 280px; display: inline-block; position: relative;''>
        <div style='display: inline-block; max-width: 450px; max-height: 260px; margin: 12px; float: left;' class='baseThumb'>
            <img src='$fromDatabaseThumb' style='max-width: 450px; max-height: 260px'>
        </div>
        <div class='baseInfo' style='display: inline-block; width: 250px; height: 253px; margin-top: 12px;'>
            <h3 style='margin: 0; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 250px; max-height: 22px; overflow: hidden;'>$fromDatabaseTitle</h3>
            <p style='margin-top: 8px; word-wrap: break-word;'>
                <strong>Description:</strong><br>
                " . $fromDatabaseDescription . "
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        ";
        }
```

`getBase()` function

```
public static function getBase($what = '*') {
self::construct();
if( is_array($what) ){
  $columns = implode("`,`", $what);
  $columns  = "`{$columns}`";
}else{
  $columns = $what != "*" ? "`$what`" : "*";
}

$sql = self::$dbh->prepare("SELECT {$columns} FROM baselayouts");
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if( !is_array($what) ){
  $data = $what == "*" ? $data : $data[$what];
}
return $data;
}
```

***The ERROR:***
[image]

***WHAT I DID***

I have done research and couldn't find anything that worked. So I tinkered around my code a bit and still couldn't fix it.

***EXTRA INFO***

I did a var_dump() since I saw in other posts that was facing the same problem as I am did a var_dump() so I thought I would do it just in case that would help you guys in any way.

`var_dump()`

```
array(4) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["base-title"]=> string(14) "Base Layout #1"
    ["base-thumbnail"]=> string(24) "/res/img/baseLayout1.png"
    ["base-description"]=> string(73) "This is the base test description. Hopefully it does what it needs to do."
}
```

Comment: what lines exactly are 16-18? **EDIT** figured it out, can you do `var_dump($LS::getBase());` prior to your foreach loop?

Comment: @iam-decoder Yes 16-18. **EDIT** Okay, let me do that right now.

Comment: @iam-decoder It gave me the same var_dump() result as last time.

Comment: then your problem is that it's setting `$base` equal to the values. Inside your foreach loop do `var_dump($base);` and you'll see that the `$base` is not an array, so there's no way to access the key's you've specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreach loop like that doesn't call the method on each iteration. It is called once on the first loop and then each later iteration loops over that returned value. So calling `getBase` is returning one row from the query and then you are loop over each column from that result making `$base` inside the loop the value in that column, not the array of the row. The var_dump appears to be return return from `getBase`, but not `$base` inside the loop. If you did a `var_dump($base);` in the loop you would see each string once. To fix it, you likely want to change your `getBase` to call [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which will return a 2d array like `$result[rowNum][colName]`.

Edit: Also, switching the loop to another structure like a `while` loop that would evaluate the full statement on each iteration would put you into an infinite loop as each time you call `getBase` you would re-query, return the first row and repeat.

Comment: @repeatercreeper Let me know if this isn't clear enough for you or anything. I'm a little tired right now so I may have started rambling a little bit.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Oh okay! I understand a little bit more now. Thank you very much for your time. :)